# Going from VisualStudio generated Database stuff to Programmer Generated

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, devforce

I'd like to be able to better access the database so I can execute queries (primarily because I don't understand/know the API for it, but I do know SQL). I don't want to remove everything Visual Studio has done because a lot is already built upon it, but how can I get an object that I can use to execute SQL queries.

This is Visual Studio 2008, C#, and MSSQL

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question, because it is misleading to what your actually asking.

Comment: For more info on the background of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529874/selectively-filling-a-dataset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like [this](http://blog.biztalk-info.com/archive/2008/06/19/Execute_SQL_Query_from_within_a_C_function.aspx):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection String Goes Here"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE", conn))
    {
        return command.ExecuteScalar() as string;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: Good, basic rundown, but would have been better to use Db* then Sql* (best practice to use the generic ADO.net classes rather then the SQL Server ones). +1 anyways

Comment: Go for it. I think it is a nice, easy to understand example though. Don't make it too hard for the newbie.

Comment: @Matt: Considering the OP is using MSSQL, it won't be an issue.

Comment: I'd still like to at see a using statement, try/finally, or even just a note at the bottom mentioning the need to ensure the connection is closed.  A quick parameter demonstration would be nice, as well.

Comment: Ah, my wish was (mostly) granted as I typed the comment.

Comment: I aim to please... I was trying to go for more of the tutorial approach, but I guess I shouldn't assume malfist will read up on this.

Comment: I do know how to use a database by the way, you know that Rich B, so I know that I need to close the connection too.

Comment: @Malfist: You have demonstrated to me that you don't know enough, and are not willing to research yourself actually, but I should not assume anything in any post anyway.

Comment: This is going to sound so conceited, but why should I do research when people are willing to do it for me for the promise or 'rep'? No seriously, I was just asking a quick question because I was leaving work and was going to check on it when I got home. I'll go through and read up on stuff now.

Comment: @Malfist: That is an oddly lazy attitude to me, but I don't care either. But I am curious as to how you don't understand how that would make me doubt that you will properly research this.

Comment: +1 for the refactor. :) I didn't downvote you btw. This is a great answer.

Comment: Why would you ExecuteScalar() a query that selects all columns x all rows?

Answer (score 2):

You might also look into the [Data Access Application Block](http://www.codersource.net/microsoft_data_access_application_block_azam.html) - just a DLL you install in your app, which allows you to execute SQL queries and such much more simply:

```
DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(cs,CommandType.StoredProcedure,"SELECT_DATA");
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would always use the free Ideablade DevForce:

http://www.ideablade.com/

And use no SQL at all!

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking what .NET libraries you can use to execute SQL against a database? If so, start by looking at `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` (if you're using SQL Server, otherwise use `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`). `SqlCommand` has several Execute() methods that will do what you're looking for.

ADO.NET is a pretty big beast but there are tons of quickstarts and sample code out there.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you're really asking for :-), but assuming you're interested in knowing how to programatically execute a SQL query, you'll need (assuming SQL Server as the backend):

- a "using System.Data;" and "using System.Data.SqlClient;" using clause
- a "SqlConnection" object to establish your connection to SQL Server (usually combined with a ConnectionString, stored in some form of a config file)
- a "SqlCommand" object to formulate your SQL query and execute it
- some way of dealing with possible results from that query

You'll have something like:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(-connection string-);

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("...your sql query here...", connection);

connection.Open();

command.ExecuteScalar / command.ExecuteReader / command.ExecuteNonQuery
(depending on your needs)

connection.Close();
```

plus of course, some error handling.... :-)

Does that help that at all??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your question what you've got going on, but if you just want to learn how to use a SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and a DataReader object to retrieve items from a database, check this out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(VS.71).aspx